# C++ - get const access to sub string of a string

Tags: c++, string, substring, constants

Say I have a `Storage` class:

```
class Storage
{
public:

  const string& get()                     const { return m_data;      }
  const char&   get(int ind)              const { return m_data[ind]; }
  const string& get(int s_ind, int e_ind) const { /* TBD */           }

private:
  string m_data; ///< Data is so big that part of it is stored on disk
}
```

Say I have a `Writer` class that gets `const Storage&` and needs to access its data.
**My question**, is there a way to implement:

```
const string& get(int s_ind, int e_ind) const;
```

i.e, get const access to only a part of a `string`.

#### Notes:

`get()` is called countless of times and it is the **bottleneck** of my application. I'd like to avoid allocating new objects when accessing data.

Comment: returning reference to internal class members is a bad approach usually

Comment: how do you use it outside after you get it? you can't return a string without creating a string, but you may return for example pair of iterators

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only way might be to have another `std::string` member variable, where you store the [sub-string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and then return that. The compiler will usually optimize the assignment to minimize creation of temporary objects.

Comment: When accessing a sub-string of data, I don't want to allocate new objects or copy chars from `m_data`

Comment: A [string views](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3609.html) proposal was made that probably does what you're looking for more or less. Don't think it made it to the standard (yet?). Boost probably has something similar though.

Comment: @vard it is a const reference. why do you believe it is a bad approach. it is pretty standard.

Comment: The way which seems better is to provide API function in Storage class to peform write operations on it.

Comment: Regarding the function returning a single character, you should note that references are usually implemented like pointers, so returning a reference to a single constant character will possibly use some indirection when you assign the result to a variable. The same goes for the other functions too of course, unless you define a reference variable for the call. If you assign the returned reference to a non-reference variable you still make a copy.

Comment: @idanshmu yeah, it is a const reference, and std::string const reference now allows directly to change referenced string. I'm telling about whole idea to return internal class data references, which author possible moving to (remove const qualifier or use 'const_cast'). Other words I prevent this idea in your head.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to implement:

```
const string& get(int s_ind, int e_ind) const;
```

> i.e, get const access to only a part of a string.

Definitely not.

What is often done - and may resolve your bottleneck - is to create a class that stores a `const char*` and `size_t` (or equally `begin` and `end` `const char*`s, or iterators but there's no reason to *limit* this to use for data in `std::string`s).

You could then create an object that "references" text inside a `string`, and use it until any of the events that would invalidate an iterator or reference to those characters happens - see the Standard or e.g. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  It's possible to support `stream` output, comparisons, indexing etc. driven off the `std::string` hosted data.

Clearly you won't be able to pass such a class to functions that hardcode `std::string` type, but you could write it to have a similar interface, which should lessen pain.

Just as a taster (hasn't seen a compiler / flesh out as needed)...

```
class Text_Ref
{
  public:
    Text_Ref(const char* p, size_t n) : p_(p), n_(n) { }

    // intuitive values for &text_ref[x] BUT text_ref[n] may not be nul
    const char& operator[](size_t o) const { return p_[n]; }

    *** OR ***

    // text_ref[n] is nul BUT can't use &text_ref[x]
    char operator[](size_t o) const { return o == n ? '\0' : p_[n]; }

    // same design trade off as the operator[] alternatives above
    char at(size_t o) const
    {
       if (o > n) throw std::out_of_range();
       return o == n ? '\0' : p_[n];
    }

    bool empty() const { return n == 0; }

    size_t size() const { return n; }
    size_t length() const { return n; }

    int compare(const char* p) const
    {
        do
        {
            if (*p != *p_)
                return (int)*p_ - *p;
        } while (*p);

        return 0;
    }

    bool operator< (const char* p) const { return compare(p) <  0; }
    bool operator<=(const char* p) const { return compare(p) <= 0; }
    bool operator==(const char* p) const { return compare(p) == 0; }
    bool operator!=(const char* p) const { return compare(p) != 0; }
    bool operator>=(const char* p) const { return compare(p) >= 0; }
    bool operator> (const char* p) const { return compare(p) >  0; }

  private:
    const char* p_;
    size_t n;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Text_Ref& t)
{
    return os.write(t.data(), t.size());
}
```